# ggpmisc::stat_poly_eq() does not consider weighting by a variable

Tags: ggpmisc

How can I get ggpmisc::stat_poly_eq() to take into account weighting by a variable? I don't see in the documentation a parameter to include weight as it exists in geom_smooth and if I try to force it within aes() it results in 'Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: weight.' I am aware of other workarounds to print the correct equation as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549694/adding-regression-line-equation-and-r2-on-graph) but it would be so much cleaner to have it in stat_poly_eq(). Has anybody figured this out or am I missing something? Thanks everyone.

```
stuff<-structure(list(var = 2:31, mean = c(17026.5, 11028.6842105263, 
                                13113.1111111111, 11087.3679395386, 9863.8664212548, 10060.676012167, 
                                9378.01091924399, 9790.67922990444, 8569.95788246269, 8839.68511390887, 
                                7656.50625471556, 7370.78564257028, 7939.13425925926, 7541.83192090395, 
                                8845.67474747475, 8023.03099415205, 6373.05976190476, 6337.93259803922, 
                                6824.79901960784, 7450.80769230769, 6651.81884057971, 5548.59722222222, 
                                7802.78205128205, 3627.07407407407, 2471, 2248.33333333333, 1368.7, 
                                2104.25, 742, 2097.5), n = c(2L, 19L, 150L, 419L, 1562L, 3178L, 
                                                             3880L, 2965L, 4288L, 2780L, 2209L, 664L, 54L, 59L, 66L, 57L, 
                                                             50L, 34L, 34L, 26L, 23L, 18L, 13L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L
                                )), .Names = c("var", "mean", "n"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")


ggplot(data=stuff, aes(x=var, y=mean))+
geom_point()+
geom_smooth(aes(weight=n), method='lm', formula = y~x)+
stat_poly_eq(aes(label=paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep="~~~")),
           formula=y~x, label.x.npc=0.8, label.y.npc=0.8,
           coef.digits=3, parse=TRUE)
```

[figure from stuff data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2q7K.png)

```
#currently, the equation printed in the plot does not correspond to the coefficients resulting with weigth=n

truecoeff<-lm(data=stuff, mean~var, weight=n)

truecoeff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! I have created [an Issue from your message](https://bitbucket.org/aphalo/ggpmisc/issues/16/ggpmisc-stat_poly_eq-does-not-consider). This is now fixed in the development version to be submitted before 2018-07-31 to CRAN as 'ggpmisc' 0.3.0.